# How to detect key press event (ctrl+e)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect the event for ctr l+e  in java-script. My code is given below.I get  alert for ctr l and e key action separately but when i put those two condition in the and logic i don't get any output. Any suggestion where i am doing wrong ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 17  && evt.keyCode == 69) {
        alert("ctrl-e is pressed");
          event.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: `evt.keyCode == 17  && evt.keyCode == 69` won't ever be true. A property or variable cannot have two different values at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `e.ctrlKey` to check if **Ctrl** [is pressed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.ctrlKey). And `onkeypress` not, `onkeydown`. Check the updated code:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  var e = evt || window.event;
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 69) {
      alert("ctrl-e is pressed");
      e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```